# Exactly one of the following systems is solvable

Tags: optimization

1. $Ax\leq b $ and $x\geq 0 $
2. $b^{T}y<0$, $A^{T}y\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$

I can show easily that if (1) is true then (2) is not and converse too. That means both statements can not be true at same time. But I want to show that Exactly one of these is always true.

Comment: I presume $A$ and $b$ are given and the question concerns the existence of $x$ and $y$? And when you have one vector less than another, does that mean each component of the first is less than the corresponding component of the other?

Comment: Remains to prove that "neither is true" is impossible.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Duality